# map() only showing first element in list

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, if-statement, innerhtml

I am relatively new to using map() in JavaScript so I'm still in the process of learning the ropes behind it. I am struggling to pull together all of my items in my list that only include a specific word, at the minute It's only pulling through the first item in the list. Can anyone please explain to me where I've gone wrong with this and what I need to do to fix this issue?

Here is my code below for reference - Any help with this issue would be seriously appreciated.

```
<div class="target-description">
  <li>Model UK 8</li>
  <li>Model Height 5 ft 8</li>
  <li>Colour: Blue</li>
</div>

const addElement = function(){
    const targetLI = [...document.querySelectorAll('.target-description li')];
    targetLI.map((item) => {
        if (item.innerText.includes('Model')) {
            item.style.display = 'none';
            const modelwear = document.createElement("div");
            const model = {};
            let desc = item.innerText;
            model.desc = desc;

            modelwear.id = "model";
            modelwear.innerHTML = `<div class="model">
                    <span class="model-header">Model Information:</span>
                        <div class="model-grid">
                            <div class="model-img grid-item">
                            </div>
                            <div class="model-copy grid-item">
                                <span class="model-desc">${model.desc}</span>,<br>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>`;

            const homepageTarget = document.querySelector('.target-description');
            if (document.getElementById('model') === null) {   
                const parent = homepageTarget.parentNode;
                parent.insertBefore(modelwear, homepageTarget);
            } else {
                document.querySelectorAll('.model-desc').innerText = desc;
            }
        } else if (!item.innerText.includes('Model')) {
            item.style.display = "list-item";
        }
    });
};
addElement();
```

Comment: If you're not using the return value of `.map()` then `.map()` is the wrong tool.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('.model-desc').innerText` doesn't make sense, nor should an `<li>` be children of a `<div>`...  lots of problems

Comment: Thank-you for responding. What do you suggest is the best way for me to fix this? I did try this with a forEach loop aswell but was getting the exact same outcome.

Comment: So if `document.getElementById('model') === null` is not there you only add it once.... Else, you only update the text?

Comment: @epascarello yeah that's correct

Answer (score 0):

The `.map()` method simply maps out a new array based on the items in the source array. For your case, it looks like you need the `forEach()` method.

```js
targetLI.forEach((item) => { //...
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank-you for responding! I did try this with a forEach loop originally before attempting this with the map() method but the forEach loop was giving me the same outcome and only showing me the first item. Is there something else I'm missing with this?

Comment: I copied your code into a static webpage, loaded the html, then ran the JavaScript with a script tag. I think the logic of the code with the `forEach()` is sound, it may be an issue with how you are using your framework.

Comment: To better answer your question, could you provide more detailed source code or context? For example: frameworks, file-structure, stack trace if any etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that you doing right but you are miss typed

> parent.insertBefore(modelwear, homepageTarget); calling only ones
> I have attached the code below you can take a look.
> `

Model UK 8

Model Height 5 ft 8

Colour: Blue

`

```
const addElement = function(){
const targetLI = [...document.querySelectorAll('.target-description li')];
targetLI.map((item,i) => {
    if (item.innerText.includes('Model')) {
        item.style.display = 'none';
        const modelwear = document.createElement("div");
        const model = {};
        let desc = item.innerText;
        model.desc = desc;
        modelwear.id = "model";
        modelwear.innerHTML = `
            <div class="model">
                <span class="model-header">Model Information:</span>
                    <div class="model-grid">
                        <div class="model-img grid-item">
                        </div>
                        <div class="model-copy grid-item">
                            <span class="model-desc">${model.desc}</span>,<br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>`;

        const homepageTarget = document.querySelector('.target-description');            

        const parent = homepageTarget.parentNode; 
        
        if (document.getElementById('model') === null) { // in the first iteration null but int secod iteration its not null
            parent.insertBefore(modelwear, homepageTarget); // so you need pass this for
        } else {
            document.querySelectorAll('.model-desc').innerText = desc;
            parent.insertBefore(modelwear, homepageTarget); //here  too
        }
    } else if (!item.innerText.includes('Model')) {
        item.style.display = "list-item";
    }
});};addElement();
```